# error: package org.json.simple does not exist VS Code

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use json.simple package for a school project and it is repeatedly giving me the same error "error: package org.json.simple does not exist".
At first VS Code gave me the error while importing so I have added the json-simple-1.1.1.jar file to the reference library. The error in the editor itself went away but when I try to compile the code using javac it gives me all the errors regarding json.simple packages. Please help!

Comment: Did you check this https://serverfault.com/a/784178 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the run button provided by the java extension package to run the code.

[image]

If you want to use `javac` and `java` commands to run the code. Because your program references third-party library files, you need to add the `-cp` command to specify the `jar` file. If there are multiple jar files, they need to be separated by semicolons.

```
javac -cp C:\WorkSpace\JavaSql\lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar -d classes src\App.java
```

[image]